# USB Debugging on a soft brick?

Tags: usb, boot-loop, unbricking, usb-debugging

How do you enable USB Debugging on a bootloop-ed device?

Or, at least, how do you determine if a bootloop-ed device has the USB Debugging option turned on?

Comment: Hello. What are you trying to achieve though USB Debugging? This seems like an XY problem as of now. If you are trying to recover data out of a soft-bricked device, it is best to mention the Android device name, Android version  name, and whether the bootloader is unlocked and the device rooted?

Comment: SM-N910C, Samsung Note 4 — unrooted — I haven't ever touched the bootloader so I guess it's locked — Android 6.0.1. By the way, I just managed to SUCCESSFULLY flash with Odin the official firmware, but the phone continues in a bootloop!!! Amazing! And yes, I'm trying to recover my data by any means. I was so close after all this time and research ... but in the end nothing...